# Beautifulsoup Python Youtube Scrape not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm trying to scrape Youtube URLs + Title from youtube accounts which are formatted like `https://www.youtube.com/c/%s/videos %accountName`. for example [Apple](https://www.youtube.com/user/Apple/videos)

The class given to the clickable text (title) in Youtube is `ytd-grid-video-renderer #video-title.yt-simple-endpoint.ytd-grid-video-renderer` - When clicking on the title object in inspector mode (Firefox)

[image]

I am not getting any results, but the url '`url`' (somewhere in *webCommandMetadata*) and title '`simpleText`' are showing in the request.content

Example:

```
url = "https://www.youtube.com/c/%s/videos" % account
req = requests.get(url, timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
# latest_videos_html = soup.select('.yt-lockup-content:not(:has(span.yt-uix-livereminder)) .yt-lockup-title a')[:6]
# latest_videos_html = soup.select('.yt-lockup-content:not(:has(span.yt-uix-livereminder)) .yt-simple-endpoint a')[:18]
latest_videos_html = soup.select('ytd-grid-video-renderer #video-title.yt-simple-endpoint.ytd-grid-video-renderer')[:18]

print(latest_videos_html)`
```

**My question is:** How do I know what to input in the `soup.select` and how do I debug this so I could fix this in the future myself?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: you have to replace requests with selenium. Requests do not load javascript code from youtube

Comment: You could consider looking into how [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/) scrapes YouTube pages. It is written in Python as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content you see in the browser is loaded mostly by javascript. By using simple GET requests you do not receive the dynamic content of the page.

By looking at users' pages on YouTube, I can see you do not get a lot of proper HTML information, but rather you get JSONs in the `body` tag.

To answer your question, in the future when you want to scrape something from a website, first make sure you actually have the content when using `requests.get` rather than assuming that you get the same content a browser gets.

Now, specifically for the YouTube problem, if you save `req.text` in a file and open it in a file editor and open the `<body>` tag, you will see that under the `<script>` tag (the second one) the variable `window["ytInitialData"]` is set to a very-very long JSON.

Inside it there is all the available info you need for every video (title, duration, video ID, etc.). I suggest you parse that JSON and see if it solves your problem.